# PDF.js renders old report

Tags: jquery, html, ios, pdf.js

I am using PDF.js to render my PDF reports in my mobile web app for iOS. The PDF.js reads the PDF file "SalesData.pdf" from "Reports" folder. My problem is that, If I update the pdf file with new data, PDF.js continues to display the same old report. Please help me on this issue. what can I do to tackle this problem.

Note: 'I am using PDF.js github source files for my application. I give the file name to "viewer.html" for rendering.'

PDF.js github link: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/web

My code:

```
$("#iframePDF").attr("src", "MyWebapp/web/viewer.html?file=MyWebapp/Reports/SalesData.pdf");
```

Comment: Any experts around??

Comment: Firstly, can you provide some calling code which you use to retrieve the pdf. It sounds like a cache issue so something like `window.location.reload(true)` might be helpful to force a new request for the file(s).

Comment: Sometimes it is connected with to aggressive caching on a web hosting side or browsers. Sometimes even properly setting HTTP headers does not help. Create a unique file name for new version of the report.